# Outline to teach VB6

Tags: vba, vb6

I am in need of an outline on teaching VB6/VBA to some co-workers. The material I am pretty confident I can fill in, just need a sense of how to order the class material. Its not going to be hard core programming [nix the VB6 jokes please :) ] but do want to touch the basics. Any free outlines or even entire presentations out there that I can use? I've been looking but nothing concrete so far.

thanks

Comment: Yep I got you and have migrated to .NET. however we still have to support legacy programs and there is no way around that until we migrate to a newer language. Even then Vb6 is still good for quick apps. I use it internally all the time but less and less frequently.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean VBA say VBA, not VB6.  They differ a great deal based on the object models available, and the actual language syntax is a fairly simple thing to pick up.

Just look for some Dummies, O'Reilly, etc. books to use as a teaching guide.  Maybe even go with self-study making yourself available for questions and general help, and to prod them along.

Comment: I mean both. The syntax is very similar, Ive been working with both for about 10 years. If you know one its very easy to jump to the other. I may look for a book.

Answer (score 1):

Well I went to the public library and found a book called "Visual Basic In Easy Steps". that seems to have a good outline and it covers VB6 and VBA. Straight and simple.